# How to efficiently limit and then concatenate a result with a linq / lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, concatenation

I am in the process of creating a service to make it easy for a user to select a protocol from the [IANA - Protocol Registry](http://www.iana.org/protocols).

As you might imagine searching the registry for the term `http` pulls up a lot of hits. Since `amt-soap-http` is going to selected by a user much less frequently than straight `http` I decided that it would be a good idea to pull out everything that starts with `http` and then concatenate that with the remaining results.

The below lambda expression is the result of that thought process:

```
var records = this._ianaRegistryService.GetAllLike(term).ToList();
var results = records.Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(term))
                     .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
                     .Concat(records.Where(r => !r.Name.StartsWith(term))
                                    .OrderBy(r => r.Name))
                     .Take(MaxResultSize);
```

Unfortunately, I feel like I am iterating through my results more times than necessary. Premature optimization considerations aside is there a combination of lambda expressions that would be more efficient than the above?

Comment: For those (like @Bobson and the upvoter) who don't know the difference between `Orderby` and `GroupBy+SelectMany`: One is `n*Log(n)` operation and the other `n`

Comment: @I4V Using that knowledge is there a more efficient answer than the [answer D Stanley provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14884435/61654)?

Comment: ahsteele, I had given one, but I removed it after 3 downvotes(because I wrote *I haven't tested it yet*)

Comment: @I4V I'm sorry you got down voted. Unfortunately, I didn't see the answer.

Comment: How often does `MaxResultSize` exceed the number of names starting with `term`? Given the lazy nature of `Concat` but the *eager* way that values are sorted by `OrderBy` as soon as you fetch the first one, the difference between asking for 1000 items and asking for 1001 items could be huge.

Comment: @JonSkeet At this point `MaxResultSize` is set to 25 for UX purposes. There are 125 results which contain the term `http`, 23 of which start with `http`. More often than not there are many fewer items that start with the term. In total there are 13,000 records.

Comment: Arrgh!!! All these answers/comments are only for 13K items?

Comment: @L.B as I said perhaps a premature optimization, but it's an opportunity for me to better understand an algorithm. Sure what I have works, but I'm always interested in the "right" solution.

Comment: @I4V - Your example wasn't a case of `OrderBy` vs `GroupBy+SelectMany`.  You had `GroupBy+OrderBy+SelectMany`, which takes at least twice as long (in my testing) as the single `OrderBy` you are opposing and produces the same results.  You also had the sort backwards.

Comment: @Bobson a) `OrderBy` sorts only 2 times(key of the group). therefore I ignored it. b) I don't know how you made your test but my tests show that my suggestion(`GroupBy+SelectMany+2itemssort`) runs 4 times faster (with 2M items where 1M starts with `a` and 1M items with `b`)

Comment: @I4V - Running in LINQPad.  Two million instances of `new Test { ID = i, Name = i.ToString().Reverse() }`.  Sorting on starting with "12".  `OrderBy` takes approximately .0001900 seconds according to `Stopwatch`.  `GroupBy+OrderBy+SelectMany` takes approximately .0004800 seconds

Comment: @Bobson Are you materializing your Linq (ie. `.ToList()` :). Don't forget the lazy evaluation. Also run the test twice not to count the JIT time ) Adding even another `OrderBy` to sort the items in each group (`records.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                                          .OrderBy(x => !x.Key.StartsWith(term))
                                          .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Name))
                                          .SelectMany(r => r))`  results 2 times faster than a single `OrderBy` :)

Comment: @I4V - I'm adding those to a `List<Text>` in a `for` loop.  Subsequent runs: ~.0000049 for `GroupBy+Order+BySelectMany` ~.0000026 for `OrderBy` alone.  **Additional Thought:** `GroupBy(r => r.Name)` is useless because each item has a different name, so you'll get one group per item.

Comment: @Bobson, See my other answer. Run it in your environment and post the result. It is better to talk with **`code`**

Answer (score 5):

It might be more efficient as a two-step ordering:

```
var results = records.OrderBy(r => r.Name.StartsWith(term) ? 1 : 2)
                     .ThenBy(r => r.Name)
                     .Take(MaxResultSize);
```

Comment: @L.B is there a more efficient alternative to D Stanley's and my code?

Comment: @DStanley Suppose `n=2**20 (1M)`, your solution would be `1M*20`, but sorting two 0.5M items would be `(0.5M*19)*2`. Additionally, you have  `ThenBy` Which is also `(0.5M*19)*2`

Comment: @L.B I can't. I was joking about how I don't yet have super powers because of my lower reputation. Thank you for providing it. :)

Comment: @L.B - Part of the reason it was downvoted so much (and then deleted, I assume) is because **part of it is useless**.  It produces exactly the same results as `records.OrderBy(x => !x.Name.StartsWith(term))`.  So no need to group or selectmany.

Answer (score 3):

Using comment to explain what I am trying to do is getting hard. So i will post this another answer.
Suppose I want to sort a list of random integers first according to its being even or odd then in numerical order (simulating `StartsWith` with `mod 2`).

Here is the test case: *action2* is the same as other answer.

If you run this code you will see that my suggestion (`action1`) is two times faster.

```
void Test()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<int> records = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0;i<2000000;i++)
    {
        records.Add(rnd.Next());
    }

    Action action1 = () =>
    {
        var res1 = records.GroupBy(r => r % 2)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y))
                    .SelectMany(x => x)
                    .ToList();
    };

    Action action2 = () =>
    {
        var res2 = records.OrderBy(x => x % 2).ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
    };


    //Avoid counting JIT
    action1();
    action2();


    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action1();
    long t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    sw.Restart();
    action2();
    long t2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine(t1 + " " + t2);
}
```

Comment: Sorting the groups is less efficient than sorting individual records when there's only one record per group.

Comment: @Bobson Just try it. **I say it is 2 times faster**

Comment: Results **when there is only one record per group**: `3302 615`.  I took your code, replaced `rnd.Next()` with `i`, and took out the `% 2` calls.  This is a much closer approximation of the OP's question, where each value in his list was unique, and the point I've been trying to make.  If you also take out the second-order sorting from both, results are `2656 568`.

Comment: @Bobson When you take out `%2` calls you change all the logic. `%2` simulates `startsWith` method. So you have 2 groups. The random part is irrelavant to my answer, but using it is better to mimic a real sort.

Comment: That is a valid point.  I had been going off the code you posted in a comment where you grouped on `.Name` instead of `.StartsWith(.Name)`, since the original code wasn't visible any more.  This example **is** closer to the OP's question than I thought it was.

Comment: @Bobson Yeah, you are right. I had formed the answer in my mind as `records.GroupBy(x => x.StartsWith(term)).OrderBy(x => x.Key).SelectMany(r => r);` but posted as `records.GroupBy(r => r.Name).OrderBy(x => !x.Key.StartsWith(term)).SelectMany(r => r);`.